# Compute clusters (transitive closure) on a bidirectional cyclic graph in Snowflake SQL

Tags: sql, recursion, graph, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, transitive-closure

I have a bi-directional graph containing multiple clusters and non-trivial cycles, i.e. the graph contains cycles involving 3 or more nodes. The graph is represented as an edge table and the list of nodes is the set of unique nodes listed in the edge table.

A toy example of such a graph can be generated using the following SQL:

```sql
with clusters as (
    select 
        seq8() as index,
        index % 5 as five_mod,
        round((index - five_mod) / 5) as multiplier,
        index as left_node,
        case 
            when five_mod = 0 then 5 * multiplier
            when five_mod = 1 then 5 * multiplier
            when five_mod = 2 then 5 * multiplier
            when five_mod = 3 then 5 * (multiplier + 1)
            when five_mod = 4 then 5 * (multiplier + 1)
        end as right_node
    from table(generator(rowcount => 5 * 2 + 3))
)
, cycles as (
    select 
        seq8() as index,
        index % 5 as five_mod,
        round((index - five_mod) / 5) as multiplier,
        index as left_node,
        case 
            when five_mod = 1 then index + 1
            when five_mod = 3 then index + 1
        end as right_node
    from table(generator(rowcount => 5 * 2 + 3))
    where right_node is not null
)
, edges as (
    select left_node, right_node from clusters
    union all
    select left_node, right_node from cycles
)
select * from edges;
```

(The above creates a graph containing "bowtie-shaped" clusters of 5 elements. E.g., for the nodes 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 the nodes 3, 4, 6, 7 are all connected to node 5. Additionally, nodes 3, 4 and nodes 6, 7 are connected.)

**The problem**

I would like to identify clusters on this graph based on reachability, i.e., two nodes belong to the same cluster if there exists a path (sequence of connected nodes) between them. In other words, I want to build a new table that contains two columns (node_idx, cluster_idx) and one row per node which links the node to its cluster.

For the toy example above, the result would look like this:

| node_idx | cluster_idx |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 6 | 2 |
| 7 | 2 |
| 8 | 3 |
| 9 | 3 |
| 10 | 3 |
| 11 | 3 |
| 12 | 3 |

I know that this can be solved with a recursive SQL query. What I don't know is how to deal with the cycles in a way that (1) avoids infinite recursion, (2) scales to a large (>500M) number of nodes, and (3) is valid Snowflake SQL.

Does somebody know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

In graph theory, what you call a 'cluster' is usually termed a component or a clique.

In any case, a subset of vertices that are all reachable from each other and from which vertices outside the clique are unreachable.

The algorithm for finding these is straightforward.

- Create empty list of cliques
- LOOP A

  - Create empty clique
  - SELECT arbitrary unmarked vertex in graph
  - COPY selected vertex into clique
  - MARK selected vertex
  - LOOP B over unmarked vertices in graph

    - SET found FALSE
    - LOOP C over vertices in clique

      - IF B connected to C

        - COPY selected vertex into clique
        - MARK selected vertex
        - SET found TRUE
        - BREAK out of LOOP B
      - IF found == FALSE

        - BREAK out of LOOP C
    - IF found == FALSE

      - ADD clique to list of cliques
    - IF all vertices marked

      - OUTPUT list of cliques
      - STOP
- ENDLOOP A

I have no idea how you would implement that in pure SQL.  I recommend loading the adjacency lists from your database into your favorite graph theory library and either using a library method to find components, if available, or coding the algorithm using library methods.  This will be a lot easier and faster!

Answer (score 1):

As [@ravenspoint](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16582/ravenspoint) noted, this is more of a graph problem than a SQL problem. My recommendation would be to build a Snowpark for Python stored procedure using a graph library. Two such libraries present in the Snowpark repo are [python-igraph](https://igraph.org/python/) and [NetworkX](https://networkx.org/). [Here](https://python.igraph.org/en/stable/tutorials/visualize_cliques.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-visualize-cliques-py) is a start on determining cliques with igraph. NetworkX also has you covered on [cliques](https://networkx.org/documentation/latest/reference/algorithms/clique.html#module-networkx.algorithms.clique)

While you could build a SQL procedure following the above recipe, those loop constructs are going to have horrible performance, particularly with the volume of data you are working with.